# Swift 3.0 Manipulate and Call Upon Elements in MKAnnotation Array

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview

I am wondering how I am able to manipulate an array consisting of MKAnnotations. An example of this array is

```
[<MKUserLocation: 0x608000631500>, <Swift.ColorPointAnnotation: 0x600000861e00>]
```

but my issue is that when this array is generated, the order is randomized (MKUserLocation is first in the array sometimes, second other times). I was wondering if there was a way to be able to grab, in this case, Swift.ColorPointAnnotation such that I am able to manipulate the map with this annotation.

Here is how I have been manipulating the array. I wish to be able to grab the specific annotation in order to center the mapRegion around it.

```
let annotations = self.mapView.annotations
let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance((annotations.last?.coordinate)!, 500, 500)
mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this to get the first `ColorPointAnnotation` from that array.

```
if let pin = mapView.annotations.first(where: { $0 is ColorPointAnnotation }) {

    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(pin.coordinate, 500, 500), animated: true)

}
```